# screen scrape and ajax

Tags: ajax, screen, scrape

I want three tables from a page that reloads itself every two minutes. I have screen scraped the three tables using php now I want to put these three tables in a div on my page what is the best ajaxy way to do this?

should i save the three tables as a separate html file and then load them by load() or use json or ...?

Comment: @arxanas i have tried load() but i don't like this method i wanna a better and more robust way of putting html inside an element using ajax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the best method is using jquery get function

```
$.get(url [, data],function(data) {
    $("#element").html(data);
},'html')
```